# ASM: visitLabel generates too many labels and nop instructions

Tags: java, java-bytecode-asm, bytecode-manipulation, jvm-bytecode

ASM documentation says a label represent a basic block, and it is a node in the control graph. So I test the `visitLabel` method on this simple example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int x = 3, y = 4;
    if (x < y) {
        x++;
    }
}
```

For the `visitLabel` method, I instrument it with a native API: `setID(int id)`, where the id is incremental. In this example, a CFG should have 3 nodes: one at the beginning, and one for each branch of the if statement. So I expect `setID` would be called in 3 locations. However, it is called 5 times, and there are a lot of `nop` instructions. Could anybody explain for me why?

Here is the instrumented bytecode for the above program.

```
  public static void main(java.lang.String[]);
    Code:
       0: iconst_2
       1: invokestatic  #13                 // Method setId:(I)V
       4: iconst_3
       5: istore_1
       6: iconst_3
       7: invokestatic  #13                 // Method setId:(I)V
      10: iconst_4
      11: istore_2
      12: iconst_4
      13: invokestatic  #13                 // Method setId:(I)V
      16: iload_1
      17: iload_2
      18: if_icmpge     28
      21: iconst_5
      22: invokestatic  #13                 // Method setId:(I)V
      25: iinc          1, 1
      28: bipush        6
      30: invokestatic  #13                 // Method setId:(I)V
      33: return
      34: nop
      35: nop
      36: nop
      37: nop
      38: athrow
```

What I don't understand is why there is a `label` before each `istore` instruction. There is no branching to make it a new node in the CFG.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The primary purpose of a `Label` is to denote a position in the bytecode sequence. Since this is needed for branch targets, you can use them to identify basic blocks. But you have to be aware, that they are also used for reporting line numbers, when a [`LineNumberTable`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se11/html/jvms-4.html#jvms-4.7.12) attribute is present and for reporting local variable scopes when a [`LocalVariableTable`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se11/html/jvms-4.html#jvms-4.7.13) attribute is present as well as, for newer class files, their type annotations recorded in a [`RuntimeVisibleTypeAnnotations`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se11/html/jvms-4.html#jvms-4.7.20) attribute. Further, labels may mark the protected area of an exception handler. For code generated from Java source code, this protected area matches the `try` block, so its a basic block, but that doesn’t need to hold for other bytecode.

See

- [`visitLocalVariable(java.lang.String name, java.lang.String descriptor, java.lang.String signature, Label start, Label end, int index)`](https://asm.ow2.io/javadoc/org/objectweb/asm/MethodVisitor.html#visitLocalVariable-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-org.objectweb.asm.Label-org.objectweb.asm.Label-int-)
- [`visitLocalVariableAnnotation(int typeRef, TypePath typePath, Label[] start, Label[] end, int[] index, java.lang.String descriptor, boolean visible)`](https://asm.ow2.io/javadoc/org/objectweb/asm/MethodVisitor.html#visitLocalVariableAnnotation-int-org.objectweb.asm.TypePath-org.objectweb.asm.Label:A-org.objectweb.asm.Label:A-int:A-java.lang.String-boolean-)
- [`visitTryCatchBlock(Label start, Label end, Label handler, java.lang.String type)`](https://asm.ow2.io/javadoc/org/objectweb/asm/MethodVisitor.html#visitTryCatchBlock-org.objectweb.asm.Label-org.objectweb.asm.Label-org.objectweb.asm.Label-java.lang.String-)

Since the scope of local variables may span the last `return` instruction, it is possible to encounter labels after that last instruction, which is what happens in your case. You are injecting a `bipush 7, invokestatic #13` after the `return` instruction, resulting in unreachable code.

Apparently, you are also using the `COMPUTE_FRAMES` options to let ASM recalculate stack map frames from scratch, but it is impossible to calculate frames for unreachable code, due to the unknown initial stack state. ASM solves this problem by replacing unreachable code with `nop` instructions, followed by a single `athrow` statement. For this sequence, it’s possible to specify a valid initial stack frame and it has no impact on the execution (as the code is unreachable).

As you can see, four `nop` instructions plus one `athrow` instruction span five bytes, which is the same size as the replaced `bipush 7, invokestatic #13` sequence had.

You can get rid of most of these reported labels, by specifying [`ClassReader.SKIP_DEBUG`](https://asm.ow2.io/javadoc/org/objectweb/asm/ClassReader.html#SKIP_DEBUG) to its [`accept` method](https://asm.ow2.io/javadoc/org/objectweb/asm/ClassReader.html#accept-org.objectweb.asm.ClassVisitor-int-). Then, you get only one reported label for your example, the branch target associated with the `if` statement. But you have to handle the [`visitJumpInsn`](https://asm.ow2.io/javadoc/org/objectweb/asm/MethodVisitor.html#visitJumpInsn-int-org.objectweb.asm.Label-) to identify the start of the conditional code.

So, to identify all basic blocks, you have to handle all branch instructions, i.e. via `visitJumpInsn`, `visitLookupSwitchInsn`, and `visitTableSwitchInsn`, as well as all end instructions, i.e. `athrow` and all variants of `return`. Further, you need to process all `visitTryCatchBlock` calls. If you need to identify potential targets of branch instructions in a single pass, I’d use `visitFrame` instead of labels, as frames are mandatory at all branch targets for class file version of 51 (Java 7) or higher.

By the way, when all you’re injecting are these sequences of loading a constant and calling a static method (at reachable locations), I’d use `COMPUTE_MAXS` instead of `COMPUTE_FRAMES`, as an expensive recalculation is not necessary when the general code structure does not change.

Comment: thanks for the awesome answer, I understand the problem now. Using `SKIP_DEBUG` does remove unnecessary labels. However, I want to instrument each basic block with an ID, and how do I instrument returns instructions and ATHROW. I tried to override `visitInsn`, and instrumented before the visiting the return instructions, but doing this just adds many `nop` instructions like before, and no invocation method calls are added.

Comment: That sounds like a new question. You should include the code doing the transformation in the new question then. Otherwise, it’s really hard to tell.